# Firebase: deploy same app to multiple Firebase-projects

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

I´m trying to deploy my code to two different Firebase-projects, one for development and one for production.

The `my-app-dev` project was already included and working, so I added the `my-app` (for production) with `firebase use --add` and selected the `my-app`.

This is how my Firebase-config looks now:

**.firebaserc**

```
{
  "targets": {
    "my-app-dev": {
      "hosting": {
        "app": [
          "my-app-dev"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "projects": {
    "default": "my-app-dev",
    "prod": "my-app"
  }
}
```

**firebase.json**

```
{
  "hosting": [
    {
      "target": "app",
      "public": "dist/app",
      "ignore": [
        "firebase.json",
        "**/.*",
        "**/node_modules/**"
      ],
      "rewrites": [
        {
          "source": "**",
          "destination": "/index.html"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint",
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
    ]
  }
}
```

As long as I deploy to my default project, everything works fine, but when I try to `firebase deploy -P prod` it shows the following error:

```
Deploy target app not configured for project my-app. Configure with:

firebase target:apply hosting app <resources...>
```

I tried to find some more information about this command, but still don´t know what to put for resources. Overall I feel like the `.firebaserc` has a very confusing structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [comment](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/590#issuecomment-361147849) in GitHub it cannot be done without a "hacky" method like swapping the firebase.json programmatically during deploying.

> Right now the Firebase CLI is built to treat projects as anonymous
>   environments that are functionally identical. This is important to be
>   able to deploy the same assets to multiple projects without having to
>   alter the code (including in firebase.json).
>
> To achieve what you want, you'll need to set up a dev and prod folder,
>   each with their own firebase.json and each with a target only for that
>   specific project. Deploying different assets to different projects is
>   not supported now and is unlikely to be supported in the future
>   (however, we may allow configuring the location of firebase.json via a
>   flag at some point).

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem but in a different fashion.

The project I have is an Angular 11 project, which has 4 different environments - the same behaviour of deploying to the default project (env) was fine but as soon as I tried to deploy to a different environment (firebase project), it failed with the same error:
`Deploy target ___ not configured for project ___. Configure with:`

I resolved this by adding to my `.firebasesrc > targets`:

```
{
  "projects": {
    "default": "default-project"
  },
  "targets": {
    "default-project": {
      "hosting": {
        "frontend": [
          "default-project"
        ]
      }
    },
    "staging-project": { // Added this entry.
      "hosting": {
        "frontend": [
          "staging-project"
        ]
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved it to deploy to a production project and staging project:

In my `.firebaserc` file i declare the 2 projects and their sites:

```
{
  "targets": {
    "my-production-project": {
      "hosting": {
        "production": [
          "my-production-site-id"
        ]
      }
    },
    "my-staging-project": {
      "hosting": {
        "staging": [
          "my-staging-site-id"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then in my `firebase.json` I have something like that (conf might differ base on your framework, I m using nextjs here...)

```
{
  "hosting": [
    {
      "target": "staging",
      "source": ".",
      "ignore": [
        "firebase.json",
        "**/.*",
        "**/node_modules/**"
      ],
      "frameworksBackend": {
        "region": "europe-west1"
      }
    },
    {
      "target": "production",
      "source": ".",
      "ignore": [
        "firebase.json",
        "**/.*",
        "**/node_modules/**"
      ],
      "frameworksBackend": {
        "region": "europe-west1"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Finally I have Makefile with rules to deploy:

```
staging:
    @echo "Deploying to staging"
    firebase use my-staging-project
    firebase deploy --only hosting:staging

production:
    @echo "Deploying to production"
    firebase use my-production-project
    firebase deploy --only hosting:production
```

Note the call to `firebase use my-production-project`